# JFreechart color square grid on XY plot

Tags: colors, grid, jfreechart

Is it possible to assign different colors to different grid squares on an XYplot in jfreechart?
I have a chart whose grids I want to assign different values and want to assign colors based on these values
Thanks
How this can be done on an XYSeriesCollection for XYSeries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, among the [JFreeChart Samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp), `XYTaskDatasetDemo2` and `XYBlockChartDemo[1-3]` are examples.